# Why my file is not cached via the Service Broker?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, browser-cache, service-broker

I identified one file which make the Service Broker cache action to fail. Or more precisely make it caches nothing.
I have an array with the files to cache.

When this 'view/viewListAttentes.php' is commented, the process works, files are added in the Cache Storage.
But when it is not, the "site-static-v9" is created but empty. And this file IS in the folder like the others.

So do you have any idea what problem with a file can cause that ?

```
const staticCacheName = 'site-static-v9';
const assets = [
'/index.php',
'/css/global.css',
'/js/app.js',
'/js/rech.js',
'/js/rechFormFilm.js',
'/js/button.js',
'/modele/modele.php',
'/param/param.ini',
'/view/viewAjout.php',
'/view/viewFooter.php',
'/view/viewHeader.php',
// '/view/viewListAttentes.php', When commented it's working, else the cache is empty
'/view/viewMenuEnTete.php',
];

// installation of the Service Worker
self.addEventListener('install', e => {
    console.log('SW installé', e);
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(staticCacheName)
            .then(cache => {
                console.log('-------On cache en static les éléments----------');
                return cache.addAll(assets)
                            .then(e => {
                                console.log(e);
                            })
                            .catch(e => {
                                console.log("erreur addAll", e.message);
                            });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("erreur open cache", err.message);
            })
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why, but it seems that a  tag in this file make it uncacheable.... Strange, since i have many .php files, with  tags which does cache with the addAll() method.

To make it works i move this php tag in the index.php.